# Recommendation for getting data from Observable<any>

Tags: reactjs, axios, httprequest

I created a ServiceHttpWrapper which executes a http request, the response is packed into an observable, but how to I get the data of the response inside a variable?

HttpWrapper:

```
public get(params: HttpParams): Observable<any> {
    let { apiUrl } = this.configRequest(params.slugType, params.slug);

    return fromPromise(this._apiBase.get(apiUrl, params.payload)) //payload change
      .pipe(map(res => ({
        type: params.successActionType,
        payload: res
      })),
      catchError(res => of({
        type: params.errorActionType,
          action_type: params.specificErrorType,
          payload: {
            message:  res.response
          }
      })));
  }
```

_apiBase.get() is basically a axios.get request.

Outputing the request via:

```
 productApi.getProductByID('2').subscribe((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

**Console Output**

```
payload:
   { status: 200,
     statusText: 'OK',
     headers:
      { date: 'Thu, 25 Jul 2019 13:18:35 GMT',
        'content-type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'content-length': '509',
        connection: 'close',
        'set-cookie': [Array],
        'x-powered-by': 'Express',
        vary: 'Origin, Accept-Encoding',
        'access-control-allow-credentials': 'true',
        'cache-control': 'public, max-age=14400',
        pragma: 'no-cache',
        expires: 'Thu, 25 Jul 2019 17:18:35 GMT',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        etag: 'W/"1fd-XTG63SYhaP/Uo6/vgmARnL3rpBk"',
        via: '1.1 vegur',
        'cf-cache-status': 'HIT',
        age: '4336',
        'accept-ranges': 'bytes',
        'expect-ct':
         'max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"',
        server: 'cloudflare',
        'cf-ray': '4fbe6bb26d0bc2c2-FRA' },
     config:
      { url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/2',
        method: 'get',
        ....
        data: undefined },
     request:
      ClientRequest {         
        ....            
        ...,
     data:
      { id: 2,
        name: 'Ervin Howell',
        username: 'Antonette',
        email: 'Shanna@melissa.tv',
        address: [Object],
        phone: '010-692-6593 x09125',
        website: 'anastasia.net',
        company: [Object] } } }
```

Comment: Is something preventing you from assigning your variable where your `console.log` is ?

Comment: no, but I only need the part inside data from the payload...but how do I filter those?